# Defining piece-wise constant hazard function in simsurv package

Tags: r, survival-analysis, hazard

I am attempting to simulate survival data with a delayed treatment effect.
The simsurv package has been very helpful:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simsurv/vignettes/simsurv_usage.html

My approach is to define a piece-wise constant hazard function that has this form:

h(t) = λ1, for 0 ≤ t < T1

h(t) = λ2, for T1 ≤ t < T2

[image: plot]

For some reason, the simulated survival curves have large 'steps' in the second interval.
My guess is, that I can't use if-statements when defining the hazard function.

If anyone has suggestions how to fix this or knows a scource for explanations on how to define such a formula in R please let me know.

````
library(simsurv)
library(survival)

# user-defined hazard function with two intervals
piecewise_hazard <- function(t, x, betas) {
  ### calculate hazard at time t
  ifelse(test = (t <= 5), 
         yes = betas[["beta1"]], 
         no = betas[["beta2"]] * x[["treatment"]])
}

### Set simulation parameters
set.seed(1234)
n <- 1000
t_max = 10
# Covariate data
covs <- data.frame(id = 1:n,
                   treatment = rep(c(1,2), each = (n/2)))

# Population (fixed effect) parameters
betas <- c(0.02, 0.1)
names(betas) <- c("beta1", "beta2")

### Simulation
sim_times <- simsurv(hazard = piecewise_hazard, 
                       x = covs, 
                       betas = betas, 
                       maxt = t_max)
sim_data <- merge(sim_times, covs)

fit_km <- survfit(Surv(eventtime, status) ~ treatment, data = sim_data)
plot(fit_km,     #clearly needs to match prior model output
     conf.int = FALSE, 
     col = c("red", "blue"), 
     main = "Simulated delayed effect", xlab = "t", ylab = "S(t)")

# Censoring happens only at the end of follow-up at t_max
fit_km$n.censor[fit_km$n.censor > 0]```
````

Comment: You used an ifelse function. Why not use `if`?

Comment: With this as the body of the piecewise_hazard functions I get the same results: `if (t <= 5){ yes = betas[["beta1"]]} else { no = betas[["beta2"]] * x[["treatment"]]}` so my hypothesis regarding the reason for failure to satisfy expectations seems ill-founded. It is a bit odd that the curves appear odd since I might have expected some sort of random input to a simulation.  (putting in a censoring at t=5 seems to be shooting yourself in the foot since that it the time when you are expecting a change in hte underlying hazard.

Comment: Also very weird that they cross. You need to describe how you are imagining the treatments is being applied in time. I think that the construction of the dataframe might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your input so far. 
As you said, using an if-else gives the same (odd) results. 
There is no censoring at t=5. It is the time at which the hazard rates change and the treatment effect is added.
I am confident that the data frame is correct as the authors of the package use this form consistently in their documentation. The id variable is needed for merging covariates and eventtimes, the treatment indicator ensures that the blue group has twice the treatment effect as the red group. 

The crossing is just a coincidence of the blue group having fewer event in the first inteval.

Comment: The crossing is due to the additional risk after t=5 in the group that was previously at a lower risk. The puzzle for me is the source of the synchronized jumps in survival.